# Will the Kata 3n1 22 bag be big enough for a Canon 60D with 18-200mm kit lens?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-bag

I want to know if its big enough for my camera + lens. There is nowhere local where I can look at the bag before buying.

If it does fit, would it fit with a hood on the lens? (possibly backwards if not forwards)

Also any other information about that bag being a good/bad choice is appreciated but not necessary.

Comment: Have you checked with Kata? http://www.kata-bags.com/contact2.asp

Comment: @mattdm I sent them an email asking the same question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your equipment is fixed, I would have asked the question:

*What is the smallest bag that can hold the Canon 60D and 18-200mm lens?*

And the answer would probably be:

[Lowepro Toploader Zoom 50AW](http://products.lowepro.com/product/Toploader-Zoom-50-AW,2204,8.htm)

If you want to also fit the lens hood, you will want:

[Lowepro Toploader Zoom 55AW](http://products.lowepro.com/product/Toploader-Zoom-55-AW,2205,8.htm)

These bags are great and make it easy to access your camera. I own the even bigger
Zoom Pro 75AW which fits my 60-250mm lens and I often configure it for two lenses
(smaller ones though), the a second one below the camera and lens.

Comment: That bag is also a lot less expensive then the Kata. I wonder, can you wear it as a backpack? Thanks.

Comment: It is usually worn across the shoulder, gives you immediate access to your camera and keeps it where you can see it. They can also be worn as belt-packs since they have a loop to pass your belt through. If you go with the 'Pro' version, it comes with a harness that is meant to be worn in front, maybe you can *try* as a backpack if you truly want. See: http://products.lowepro.com/product/Toploader-Pro-70-AW,2130,8.htm and click on view 7 & 8.

Comment: Thanks, I ordered th 55, I think it will make a good started bag, then I can upgrade to the kata 33 later if needed.

Comment: Got the bag, it fits with the hood on and still room so spare.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Kata and this is what hey said:

> The Canon 60D with the 18-200 lens
>   attached should fit in the 3N1-22.
>   However, it will only fit vertically,
>   which means that you won't be able to
>   use the Quick Access feature of the
>   bag. In the 3N1-33 – there shouldn't
>   be a problem.

Which sucks because the -33 looks gigantic, too big to tote around everywhere, and whats the point of forking over the money for a high end bag when you can't use it right.

Comment: The 3N1-33 is indeed a big bag, but not really "gigantic". If you are already willing to carry a big backpack (the -22 isn't a small one), then the difference might not be that great. However, if this is the *only* equipment that you will carry, then it definitely an overkill. If not, or if thinking about "a place to grow", then the -33 is a good choice.

Comment: I use the -33 to carry my 7D, 70-200/2.8, 10-22, 28-135, 50/1.4, 580EXII, some accessories in the top compartment, and the 15.4" laptop, when needed.